# How to let gdb break at watchpoint write even when value is unchanged

Tags: gdb, watch

I try to follow the process of a threaded application by writing a log file that should record every write operation to a global variable even when the value does not change. Gdb documentation states that 'watch' only breaks if the value changes. The problem is that recording all accesses with 'awatch' would be way too much to log. Is there a way to log all, changing and not, write operations?
My script so far:

```
set pagination off
set logging file variable_writes.txt
set logging on

file EXECUTABLE

# need hardware watchpoint for multi thread support
watch SOME_VARIABLE
commands
    silent
    p /x SOME_VARIABLE
    bt 2
    continue
end

run

set logging off
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to get nonmodifying writes is to use awatch. It hepled to limit the amount of recorded data by enabling/disabling the watchpoint in a narrow range around the interesting part.

My final script I used:

```
set pagination off
set output-radix 16
set logging file trace_variable.txt
set logging on

file EXECUTABLE

# need hardware watchpoint for multi thread support
awatch SOME_VARIABLE
commands 1
    bt 1
    continue
end

break SOME_POINT_BEFORE
commands 2
    enable 1
    continue
end

break SOME_POINT_AFTER
commands 3
    disable 1
    continue
end

# Watchpoint is enabled/disabled when reaching other breakpoints
# Starting disabled
disable 1

run

set logging off
quit
```